# Detect when div is visible on viewport for x ms

Tags: javascript

I'm searching for the best way to know when user scrolls and see a x percentage from specific div (or list of) for specific time.

Is the best way to use `onscroll` event? Is there any other way? (I'm afraid from performance issues)

Is this the best way?
On scroll event - check if the div is visible as threshold - if it does run a counter until next scroll - then check again if so -> continue to count until time wanted achieved.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please read the [help]. Your question is not clear, currently, and is likely to be closed. Please note SO is for [for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). It may be worth you creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to aid in people understanding your question

Comment: How do you know that kate is not a 'professional and enthusiast programmer'?

Comment: Use requestAnimationFrame instead of scroll event

Comment: @powerbuoy how do I use this instead? Why?